# A strategy for correctly betting on coin flips

Tags: probability

I want to increase the probability that I will guess the coin flip correctly above $0.5$. This is my strategy:

Keep a record of all previous outcomes of coin flips. If the number of tails is equal or greater than the number of tails, I bet on heads in the next round. Otherwise, I bet on tails in the next round.

This hopes to exploit the fact that the proportion of heads and tails will converge to $1$. Hence, if there have been more tails than heads previously, we should expect the next flip to be heads, because the ratio ultimately converges to $1$, and the same reasoning holds for the situation where more heads have been thrown.

I've written a simple Python program to test this idea:

```
import random

numberOfFlips = 1000000

def smartBets():    # 0: heads; 1: tails
counter = 0
partialProbability = random.randint(0, 1)
flipSum = partialProbability
for i in range(2, numberOfFlips):
    flip = random.randint(0, 1)
    if partialProbability >= 0.5:
        if flip == 0:       # bet on heads
            counter += 1 
    else:
        if flip == 1:       # bet on tails
            counter += 1
    flipSum += flip
    partialProbability = flipSum / i

return counter / numberOfFlips

print(f"Smart bets probability: {smartBets()}")
```

My tests show that my method fails. The probability of being correct still converges to $0.5$. I am interested in why this is so, which perplexes me, as my reasoning intuitively seems to be correct. Thank you for your insights! :)

Comment: You are falling victim to the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).  The coin doesn't "remember" what it has come up before...each trial is independent of the others.

Comment: @lulu Thanks... Though it still seems sensible to me to expect that, if I've flipped $10$ tails, the next one should be heads, because the ratio ultimately converges to $1$... I don't know, this still seems intuitively right to me. But I guess I'm wrong...

Comment: If you've flipped 10 tails, then eventually you'll have flipped a million coins, and the first 10 won't matter; the coin doesn't auto-correct. @Godbless

Comment: @Adam If I am reading correctly, you can extend that to an arbitrary number. Even if I were to flip an arbitrarily large number $n$ of tails, there is still an infinite amount of flips waiting which will correct that number, no matter how big it is.

Comment: Yes, exactly. @Godbless

Comment: What you’re doing is crafting a gambling strategy (or a Doob transform, or a discrete stochastic integral, or an $H$-transform…), and it’s a theorem that as long as your strategy of what to bet on at time $t+1$ uses only the information you gained up to time $t$, then your expected winnings at the next time will be your current balance at time $t$. In other words, when you are playing a fair game like this (these are called martingales), you can never pick a strategy that gives you net winnings in expectation. In this simple game, it’s because the coin flips are independent.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Thanks, I suspected that there is no winning strategy. :)

Comment: Probabilities can be unintuitive. Infinity can be unintuitive. Here you're dealing with both.

Comment: Note that the ratio of heads to tails can converge to $1$ as the number of flips $n\to\infinity$; and at the same time, the absolute difference of the number of heads versus the number of tails can get arbitrarily large values. In fact both these (seemingly contradictory) behaviors will occur "almost surely" (i.e., with probability $1$) for the same sequence of flips of a fair coin.

Answer (score 1):

I think lulu's answer is the comments is really precise:
You are falling victim to the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy). The coin doesn't "remember" what it has come up before. Each trial is independent of the others by definition as well as by your implementation.

Also, I don't really understand what you mean by the formulation "ratio ultimately converges to 1".

However, I want to add the following consideration:
If you are not sure whether the coin is fair or not, *then* your strategy is optimal. If, say, the number of heads of the first $n-1$ tosses was larger than the number of tails, then it is more likely that the coin favors heads and you should therefore bet on heads in the $n$-th toss.

You can modify your experiment to reflect this: Choose the probability $0 < p < 1$ of getting heads randomly instead of $p=0.5$ in the very beginning (with any probability distribution, e.g. uniform on [0,1]), modify the inequality $\text{partialProbability} >= 0.5$ correspondingly and repeat your experiment. On average, you should start winning.